# extern NSString * constants nil for test target

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest

I recently added added a test target (using XCTest) to my app in Xcode 5.1. Everything seems to be working fine, I can use all the classes etc. from the main app, but some extern `NSString *` constants (i.e. declared in a .h file, defined in a .m file) from my app are nil when used in the test code. I tried including the .m file in compile sources for the test target, which fixes them being nil but creates other issues (a class defined in that .m file then exists in duplicate, i.e. the test target has a different Class instance for the class). I'm testing on an iPhone 5S running iOS 7.1.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, extern NSString* definitions are not testable normally (so need refactoring).

Comment: They are error keys which I need to use in tests to see if the right error is being omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently define your real NSString objects at the top of a .m file, independent and probably even outside the "`@interface`" category declaration and the "`@implementation`" code for some object.

Why not create a ***NEW*** .m file that does ***NOT*** contain a "`@implementation`", but instead only contains the NSString constants?

And then add that new .m file (which doesn't have an associated class) as a compiled file in both your app and your test targets.

Comment: Yeah I'll just separate the constants in their own file, though I was wondering whether there was a better way to do this, whether I was doing something wrong.